# Find big folder and compress with split

Tags: linux, bash

I want to find big folder that more than 1G from server A located at destination A. The folder name is using unique name. The result from big folder will join using tar and split it into 100MB.

After split, it's will transfer using scp to destination B. Because of security issue i cannot use rsync transfer protocol.

After reach destination B, on server B i want it combine a split tar and compress to destination folder with unique name.

By manual, i can do. But to put on bash script i have no idea how to start it. I have zero knowledge in bash script. Please assist me.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `rsync` with the `ssh` protocol, that is equally secure to scp.

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I will put some command and you will need to understand how you should write a script for your specific needs.

By running this command you will find which folder you have that above then 1G in size

du -h / | awk {'print $1'} | grep G

after you will find the size of the folders (for example 10G ) you can run command

du -h /  | grep 10G | awk {'print $2'}

and you will see the name of the folder with this size

You can use ">" symbol to redirect the output to some file and read from this file after that.

You can use command like:

X=`du -h / | awk {'print $1'} | grep G``

just remove the second backtick at the end

to store the output of the command in X and use this variable later, but you should not start write this type of script with zero knowledge.

and after that:

du -h /  | grep $X | awk {'print $2'}

Please take a look on youtube tutorials for bash script and you will understand how to assemble this command to one script.

Good luck